# How to increment a counter according to the decimal part of a real number

Tags: java

I want to increment or decrement a counter according to the decimal part of a real number we don't know its value (we calculate its value each time)
this value must be in the range [0,1].

if the real number has 1 digit after the decimal point the counter will increment with 0.1,

Ex: u = 0.5 then cpt = 0.5+0.1.

if it has 2 digits after the decimal point the counter will increment with 0.01

Ex : u = 0.08 so cpt=0.08+0.01

it can also decrement in this way.
for exemple :

```
u = 0.5 
if (instructions){
cpt = u +0.1; //0.6
}
else 
cpt = u-0.1 //0.4
```

but we kan have this :

```
u= 0.1
if (instructions){
cpt = u +0.1; //0.2
}
else 
cpt = u-0.01 //0.09
```

in this case we increment with 0.1 but we decrement with 0.01 because if we decrement with 0.1 we will have u = 0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. It is unclear what your problem is or what you are trying to do. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have, maybe even post a [mcve] which we can test.

Comment: @Progman thank you for your remark i am a new member and i don't understand english very well i do my best to improve, i gave 2 other examples to better detail the question

Comment: First thing I would try, is to go with BigDecimal instead of real or doubles. This will fix your another problem.  BigDecimal.remainder() gives you decimal part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lines work well for me, I tried values like `u = 0.5` and `u = 0.580070`. The resulting `delta` you can either add or subtract to calculate `cpt`.

```
var u = 0.5;
var exponent = BigDecimal.valueOf(u).scale();
var delta = Double.valueOf("1.0E-" + exponent).doubleValue();
```

I found that the resulting value is more precise using String conversion than doing exponential arithmetics like `Math.pow(0.1, exponent)` where you get rounding errors.